# linear fit using gam in R (mgcv)

Tags: r, linear-model, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I compare different gam model fits, and I want to know if supposing a null smooth term dimension argument (`k = 0`) is equivalent to a linear regression.

lets take for instance, a gam model (of mgcv library) and a linear model:

```
mod1 <- gam(VD ~ s(VI, k=O), data = df)
mod2 <- lm(VD ~ VI, data = df)
```

Is `mod1` equivalent to `mod2`? and is there a way to define a linear model using the `s()` function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not equivalent, the s() function will reset your k:

```
mod_s <- gam(mpg ~ s(hp,k=0), data = mtcars)
Warning message:
In smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
  basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible

plot(mpg ~ hp,data=mtcars)
lines(50:350,predict(mod_s,data.frame(hp=50:350))
```

[image]

If you would like a null smooth term, maybe try:

```
mod_null <- gam(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
mod_lm <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mpg ~ hp,data=mtcars,main="gam")
lines(50:350,predict(mod_null,data.frame(hp=50:350)),col="red")
plot(mpg ~ hp,data=mtcars,main="lm")
lines(50:350,predict(mod_lm,data.frame(hp=50:350)),col="blue")
```

[image]